Derivative of trace involving product and function of matrix
I have the following matrix expression:
$$\mathrm{Trace}\left( \mathrm{A}^\intercal f(\mathrm{X})\right)$$
In the above, $f(\mathrm{X})$ is given by:
$$f(\mathrm{X}) = \left(\mathrm{B}^\intercal \mathrm{C}\mathrm{B} + \mathrm{X}\right)^{-1}$$
I want to differentiate the first expression with respect to the matrix $\mathrm{X}$. I have calculated the derivative of $f(\mathrm{X})$ with respect to $\mathrm{X}$ to be equal to $ -\left(\mathrm{B}^\intercal \mathrm{C}\mathrm{B} + \mathrm{X}\right)^\intercal \left(\mathrm{B}^\intercal \mathrm{C}\mathrm{B} + \mathrm{X}\right) $ and based on the matrix cookbook and the chain rule it seems like I should get:
$$\frac{\partial \mathrm{Trace}\left( \mathrm{A}^\intercal f(\mathrm{X})\right)}{\partial \mathrm{X}} = \mathrm{A}^\intercal \frac{\partial f(\mathrm{X})}{\partial\mathrm{X}} = -\mathrm{A}^\intercal \left(\mathrm{B}^\intercal \mathrm{C}\mathrm{B} + \mathrm{X}\right)^\intercal \left(\mathrm{B}^\intercal \mathrm{C}\mathrm{B} + \mathrm{X}\right)$$
Is this correct or am I missing something here?

The expression $\mathrm{A}^\intercal \frac{\partial f(\mathrm{X})}{\partial\mathrm{X}}$ is not quite correct. What is it supposed to mean? Note that $\frac{∂ f(X)}{∂X}$ is a 4th order tensor.

Is $f(X)$ a scalar? What are the dimensions of $A$ and $X$? You have to define your terms.

Just edited; $f(\mathrm{X})$ is a matrix expression involving $\mathrm{X}$ and 2 additional matrices $\mathrm{B}$ and $\mathrm{C}$ which are not related to $\mathrm{X}$ in any way.

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\bR#1{\big(#1\big)}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}
\def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
$Let
$$\eqalign{
Y &\equiv B^TCB &\q\{{\sf constant\ matrix} \} \\
F &= f(X) \;\equiv\; \LR{X+Y}^{-1} &\q\{{\sf matrix\ valued\ function} \} \\
dF &= -F\,\c{dF^{-1}}\,F &\q\{{\sf differential\ of\ }F \} \\
  &\equiv -F\,\c{dX}\,F \\
\phi &= \trace{A^TF} &\q\{{\sf scalar\ valued\ function} \} \\
  &\equiv A:F &\q\{{\sf Frobenius\ product\ notation} \} \\
}$$
Then calculate the differential and gradient of $\phi$
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= A:\c{dF} = -A:F\,\c{dX}\,F = -F^TAF^T:\c{dX} \\
\grad{\phi}X &= -F^TAF^T \\
}$$

You shouldn't use $\operatorname{tr}(A^T B)$. Use $⟨A∣B⟩$ instead (Frobenius inner product / tensordot). Note that  $g：ℝ^{m×n}→ℝ，Z↦⟨A∣Z⟩$ is a linear function, so equal to it's own derivative.
Let $f(X)$ denote the Fréchet derivative of $f$ at $X$. Then, by the chain rule the derivative of $h=g∘f$ is:
$$\begin{aligned}
(g∘f)(X) &= g(f(X)) ∘ f(X)
\\ &= [Z⟼⟨A∣Z⟩] ∘ [∆X ⟼ f(X)(∆X)]
\\ &= [∆X ⟼ ⟨A∣f(X)(∆X)⟩]
\\ &= [∆X ⟼ ⟨A∣_{f, X} ⋅ ∆X⟩]  \qquad \text{tensor representation of $f(X)$}
\\ &= [∆X ⟼ ⟨_{f, X}^T A∣∆X⟩]  \qquad \text{definition of the dual}
\\ &= [∆X ⟼ ⟨(A^T _{f, X})^T∣∆X⟩]
\\ &= [∆X ⟼ ⟨\operatorname{VJP}(f, X, A)^T ∣∆X⟩]\qquad \text{vector Jacobi product}
\end{aligned}$$
So, the derivative $(g∘f)(X)$ is the linear function $∆X⟼⟨\operatorname{VJP}(f, X, A)^T ∣∆X⟩$ which can be encoded in the matrix $ = \operatorname{VJP}(f, X, A)$. (Note: if $ϕ(x) = ⟨v∣x⟩$, then $∇ϕ(x)=⟨v|$, $_{ϕ, x} = |v⟩$ and $ϕ(x)=[∆x↦⟨v∣∆x⟩] = ϕ$).
References

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_inner_product
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative
https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/autodiff_cookbook.html

Example (python)
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
import numpy as np

m, n = 3, 2
A = np.random.randn(m, n)
X = np.random.randn(m, n)

def g(Z): return jnp.tensordot(A, Z) # same as trace(AᵀB), but in O(n²)
def f(X): return X * X  # element-wise product
def h(X): return g(f(X))

print(jax.grad(h)(X))  # automatic gradient
_, f_vjp = jax.vjp(f, X)  # manual gradient
f_vjp(A)  # should be the same.


Thanks a lot for this; it is a very detailed answer and well-explained. I am not very familiar with Fréchet derivatives so I am wondering if this can be somehow expressed using matrix notation? Also, why is it not a good idea to use the trace notation?

@HeyCool08 Trace is a bad idea, because people end up implementing the operation this way, which is $O(n^3)$, but the inner product costs only $O(n^2)$.

@HeyCool08 The Fréchet derivative is really the "true" derivative. What one can use is the fact that every linear function between finite dimensional vector spaces has a tensor representation. If $f：→$ is linear, then there is some tensor $_f∈⊗^$ that encodes $f$. For example, if $f：ℝ^{m×n}→ℝ^{k×l}，X↦AXB^T$, then $_f$ is a 4-th order tensor, namely an element of $⊗^=ℝ^{k×l}⊗(ℝ^{m×n})^*$. In fact, it can be written as $f(X) = AXB^T = (A⊗B)⋅X = _f⋅X$. Note that the $"⋅"$ does not represent matrix multiplication here, but a tensor contraction over 2 axes.
